# Copy several files into one if they exist

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a single batch file that runs the following code:

```
COPY IDSA14OP*  +   IGSA14OP*   +   IGSG14OP*  +  IGCO14OP*   IDSA14OP.328
```

Problems come in as at times one for the four files may not exist.  Here is what I have so far, but again, not knowing which if any of the four may not be present gets me confused on how to build the script.

```
@echo off

::Set Date Variable
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=:,.-/ " %%I in ("%DATE%") do set DT=%%I%%J

::Set File Name Vars
set v0=
set v1=IDSA14OP*
set v2=IGSA14OP*
set v3=IGSG14OP*
set v4=IGCO14OP*
set ext=IDSA14OP.%DT%

IF EXIST %v1% set v0=Copy %v1% +   
IF %v0%==NULL set v0=Copy         
IF EXIST %v2% set v0=%v0% %v2% + 
IF %v0%==NULL set v0=Copy
IF EXIST %v3% set v0=%v0% %v3% + 
IF %v0%==NULL set v0=Copy
IF EXIST %v4% set v0=%v0% %v4%

set v0=%v0% %ext%

echo %v0%
```

Comment: Do you want to skip the entire process if some files don't exist, or just append the files that do exist?

Comment: append the files that do exist

Comment: getting error - if was unexpected at this time when using below answer

Comment: try to insert a `do` between `)` and `if exist...`

Comment: What's the problem if one doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Added `do` keywords

Test this: it should append the files that do exist

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
IDSA14OP*
IGSA14OP*
IGSG14OP*
IGCO14OP*
) do if exist %%a call set line=%%line%% + %%a
echo copy /b %line:~2% IDSA14OP.328
pause
```

Here is another option if the files are text files:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
IDSA14OP*
IGSA14OP*
IGSG14OP*
IGCO14OP*
) do if exist %%a type %%a >>IDSA14OP.328
pause
```

Comment: Using the above I came up with if exist %v1% type %v1%>>%ext% and so forth, seems to work on initial testing.  Thanks for the help